# React Testing - get text inside an element

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am coding a couple of tests for my app. I want to check that after saving time, it goes to the list.

Now I got this test working by finding a text from the screen, but I want to specify it by id. I mean to check that this `00:01:00` is really in the right place, not just somewhere on the page. I hope guys understand what I mean.

How can I do this?

This is working by finding from screen:

```
test("Time saved", async () => {
  render(<SecondTimer />);

  const start = screen.getByText("START");
  fireEvent.click(start);

  await waitFor(() => screen.getByText(/00:01:00/i), {
    timeout: 2000
  });

  const pause = screen.getByText("PAUSE");
  fireEvent.click(pause); 

  const saveTime = screen.getByText("SAVE TIME"); 
  fireEvent.click(saveTime); 

  const history = screen.queryByText(/00:01:00/i);

  screen.debug(); // printtaa renderinnin consoliin
});
```

I have DIV like this:

```
<div data-testid={'aikalista'} className={'tulostaulu'}>
            <ul>
              {this.state.aikoja === false && ('No times my friend!')}
              {this.state.aikoja === true && (<div>{this.state.history.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}</div>)}
            </ul>
```

This is what I've tried with different variations, but no luck.

```
test("Time saved v2", async () => {
  render(<SecondTimer />);

  const start = screen.getByText("START");
  fireEvent.click(start);

  await waitFor(() => screen.getByText(/00:01:00/i), {
    timeout: 2000
  });

  const pause = screen.getByText("PAUSE");
  fireEvent.click(pause); 

  const saveTime = screen.getByText("SAVE TIME"); 
  fireEvent.click(saveTime); 

  const aikalista = screen.getByTestId('aikalista');
  expect(getByTestId('aikalista').textContent).toEqual(/00:01:00/i)



  screen.debug(); // printtaa renderinnin consoliin
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getByText has this signature.

```
getByText(
  container: HTMLElement, // if you're using `screen`, then skip this argument
  text: TextMatch,
  options?: {
    selector?: string = '*',
    exact?: boolean = true,
    ignore?: string|boolean = 'script, style',
    normalizer?: NormalizerFn,
  }): HTMLElement
```

You can you use this selector property inside options object to select the element. So you can write something like this.

```
screen.getByText(/00:01:00/i, {selector: "#someId"})
```

You can check if the element has an id you want after you get it by text also.

```
const element = screen.getByText(/00:01:00/i);
expect(element).toHaveAttribute('id', "someId");
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified your sample little to get it working. I have now only one `li` element and thats where saved times is going. So I did it like this `screen.getByText(/00:01:00/i, {selector: 'li'})`.